# tigervnc server fails with HOME variable not set

Tags: fedora, vnc

The system is Fedora Core 24. It is a recent upgrade from fc23. With fc23 the vncserver started without error. However after the upgrade the follow error occurs:

```
Unit vncserver@:2.service has begun starting up
vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set
```

There have not been any changes to and of the start scripts or `.vnc` files. Where would vncserver be looking for the `HOME` variable? Where would the command to set the `HOME` variable be inserted? What would it look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `HOME` environment variable is set automatically when you log in. Under normal circumstances you shouldn't find any of the login scripts modifying it in any way.

Environment variables are usually passed unmodified to programs executed in your login session. And there is hardly ever a reason to unset `HOME`, thus the error condition you mention does not sound very likely.

You can try this command to see your current environment variables:

```
tr '\0' '\n' </proc/$$/environ
```

And you can replace `$$` with the pid of any process whose environment variables you want to see (though there are obviously security restrictions to which processes you are allowed to look at, if you are not root).

If you find that `HOME` does exist when you invoke the above from your shell, you can try using `strace` to see at which point they disappear. You can try:

```
strace -fve execve vncserver
```

This will run `vncserver` and show you which environment variables were passed to `vncserver` and anything executed by `vncserver`.

Finally you can try creating a new user to see if the problem relates to a specific user's configuration files or is a systemwide problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your service is not already running with old config file, go to `/root/.vnc` dir and check if there are no any file `yourhostname:1.pid`. If it is present, do cat and find the pid which is inside the file, then do kill -9 pid. After that try to start vncserver service again.

Comment: i think you should be adding more details, as it currently is insuffitent in my eye to answer the original Question. and also why not use ps auxwww |grep vncserver where vncserver is the executable?